# how to align UL inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I have unordered list inside a div. I use it to create buttons in menu.

```
#tagscontainer
{
    width: 700px;
    height: 50px; 
    margin: auto;
}

#tagscontainer li
{
    margin-right: 1em;
    float: left;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
}


<div id="tagscontainer">
<ul>

<li><a href="menu1"> Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="menu2"> Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="menu3"> Link 3</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

I want items to be centered vertically in hosting DIV. Also what is best practice to set height for ul or for li in menus like that. Basically I want my button to be larger than text with some IDENTICAL indent from parent div ceiling and floor.

[image]

Comment: Why do you float your li elements?

Comment: Kristian, I need my buttons to go horizontally if I remove  float: left; then my items will go vertically.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "I want items to be centered vertically". I understand you want the buttons to be horizontal across the page, but by centered vertically do you want them in the middle of the page (half way down)? Or you you want them centered **horizontally** (half way across)

Comment: Guys, I made the picture, hope it clarifies my intentions. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Leigh, what I meant was my buttons positioned in the middle of Y axis in the DIV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright lets try again: Your div has a height of 50px. If your distance is 10px that leaves us with 30px for the li's.

```
li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the CSS:

```
#tagscontainer li
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%; /*these last two are needed for vertical centering*/
}
```

You have to also keep the width on the parent. `width: 700px;`

As `ul` and `li` is a block level element, it can accept height and width :)

Comment: This is horizontal centering?

Comment: "I want items to be centered vertically in hosting DIV" It's not, the OP asked for Vertical centering.

Answer (score 1):

Use vertical-align.

For details see [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Answer (score 1):

Hilarity ensues, you can always try this ugly hack. Also, does anyone know a way to fix this code? Use this code at your own risk, I accept kn ow responsibility for usage of this code :P

```
#tagscontainer li
{
    display: table-cell;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    width: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I want to do a horizontal menu, I do something like this:

```
<ul class="menucontainer">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

the CSS:

```
.menucontainer
{
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menucontainer li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.menucontainer a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```